# if Empty statement is not working in LookupOrderedRows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Here in my code i am checking `assignedsalesoffice` field.  If it's empty then i will check `salesoffice` field and displaying meeting details.

I have two DEs: `Interest_France` (subscriber) and `Result_InfoMeeting_France` (meeting detail).

Data for reference: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16E8LSASH0wgRa_bR0Hk9lCAkcyCtqh8xknwn3qwyVbo/edit?usp=sharing)

Can anybody clarify on my code because the same code was working fine last time when i tried but not today.

```
%%[

SET @rs1 = LookupRows("Interest_france","MarketCode",'FRP')
set @rowCount1 = rowcount(@rs1)

if @rowCount1 > 0 then
    SET @row = Row(@rs1,1)
    SET @AOffice1 = field(@row,"Assignedsaleoffice")
endif

if Empty(@AOffice1) then
    SET @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Result_Meeting",5,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",[SalesOffice],"MeetingType","off")
else
    Set @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Result_Meeting",5,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",[Assignedsaleoffice],"MeetingType","off") 
Endif 

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    SET @row = Row(@rs,@i)
    SET @meetingDate = field(@row,"MeetingDate")
    SET @MeetingID = field(@row,"MeetingID")

    if (@meetingDate > Now()) Then
]%%

<!-- Meeting deatils to show here -->

%%[
    endif
next @i
]%%

%%[
else
/* different content to show here */
endif
]%%
```

Comment: You shouldn't be posting real customer data in your worksheet.

Comment: sorry about that Adam, i thought it would be very useful to understand the data on which i am working on. can you solve my problem and amscript? thanks

Comment: I'm sure these people in your spreadsheet would not appreciate having their email addresses posted on a public website.

Comment: Adam, i have removed all the email address.

Comment: Thanks for providing the data, but you really haven't given us any details about 1) the values of the inputs in your test and 2) your desired output.  Without those two things there will be a lot of guessing in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing out your inputs.  I'd also recommend using [**AttributeValue()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) to retrieve the personalization string values.  Taking 2 minutes to indent your code helps in debugging.

```
%%[

var @SalesOffice, @Assignedsaleoffice, @rs, @rowCount

/* retrieve values from send context */
set @SalesOffice = AttributeValue("SalesOffice")
set @Assignedsaleoffice = AttributeValue("Assignedsaleoffice")

/* retrieve value for assigned sale office if blank */
if empty(@Assignedsaleoffice) then
    SET @Assignedsaleoffice = Lookup("Interest_france", "Assignedsaleoffice", "MarketCode", @FRP)
endif 

output(concat("<br>SalesOffice: ", @SalesOffice))
output(concat("<br>Assignedsaleoffice: ", @Assignedsaleoffice))

/* lookup meeting rows differently if sale office is empty */
if Empty(@Assignedsaleoffice) then
    SET @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Result_InfoMeeting_france",5,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",@SalesOffice,"MeetingType","off")
else
    Set @rs = LookupOrderedRows("Result_InfoMeeting_france",5,"MeetingDate Asc","info_saleoffice",@Assignedsaleoffice,"MeetingType","off") 
Endif 

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        var @meetingDate, @MeetingID, @MeetingURL

        SET @row = Row(@rs,@i)
        SET @meetingDate = field(@row,"MeetingDate")
        SET @MeetingID = field(@row,"MeetingID")
        Set @MeetingURL = CONCAT('http://infomeetings/v3/?infomeetingId=',@MeetingID)

        if (@meetingDate > Now()) Then
        ]%%

        <!-- Meeting deatils to show here -->

        %%[
        endif

    next @i

    ]%%

    %%[
else
/* different content to show here */
endif
]%%
```

Comment: Adam, i checked with data, same issue my script is not picking salesofficecode when assignedsalaofficecode is empty.  i have a doubt on first lookup, which is subscriber table. for your information salesoffice, assignedsalaoffice fields are present in subscribertable and info_saleoffice is present in meeting table. can you confirm me. whether my code is proper or not? thanks

Comment: What are the values of `AOffice1`, `SalesOffice` and `Assignedsaleoffice` in your test?

Comment: if i preview for 1st,2nd record then AOffice1 -FRP SalesOffice -FRP, Assignedsaleoffice-FRP,                                                                                  3rd record AOffice1 -FRP SalesOffice -FRP, Assignedsaleoffice-nul,               4th, 5th same as 1st and 6th is AOffice1 -FRP SalesOffice -FRA, Assignedsaleoffice-null.  so my doubt is why AOffice1 is showing FRP all time,  and basically in first lookup i am taking all the rows and checking the Assignedsaleoffice field whether it is empty, if empty then i doing lookuporderrow in meeting table,

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this code works fine for me, but small question here. if i want to show only 1 qualified meeting details, where i should change the code?

Comment: i changed the `LookupOrderedRows()` from 5 to 1 but its not working!!

Comment: In my example, retrieving 1 row as opposed to 5 rows in both `lookupOrderedRows()` functions shouldn't result in it not working.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but only meetings are not showing.